# AngularJS project deployed with grunt only works on localhost:9000

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, localhost

I'm new to AngularJs and I've been scafolding my apps with Yeoman following the steps below as outlined in this [tutorial](http://www.toptal.com/angular-js/your-first-angularjs-app-part-2-scaffolding-building-and-testing).

Steps:

```
npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower

npm install -g generator-angular

yo angular

npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev

npm install karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev

grunt serve
```

When I do this it creates a file including an "/app" directory where I do my coding. Executing the command.

```
grunt serve
```

Makes it so I can view my project at

```
localhost:9000
```

However if I navigate to the project via

```
localhost:8888 (my local MAMP server)
```

I get reference and resource errors. What I'm wondering is.

1. What is grunt doing and why doesn't my project work on localhost:8888?
2. Is this approach the best way to scaffold an angular project?

Comment: Why do you want it to work on 8888?

Comment: The port is specified in your Gruntfile.js, which is generated by generator-angular. The file looks like this: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/blob/b7b72b00330ba09594f148c3a87d047c69a1a15e/templates/common/root/_Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) the `grunt serve` creates a temporary version of the app that runs on a node server which supports 'livereload'. This means that if you edit the source files, automatically the web-page hosted on :9000 will be refreshed

2) for running the app in a webserver (like the one you're running on :8888) you should use `grunt build` that creates a production-ready version of the app inside the 'dist' directory

Comment: Thanks that's give me some of the insight I was looking for. Do you think this is a good set up for working with Angular?

Comment: I think that yo-angular provides the all-in-one setup for your Angular apps (livereloading, test framework, minification, ...) and helps to be immediately proficient spending zero time on the project's scaffolding. 
In case you have special needs, you have to learn how to tune the Gruntfile.js appropriately and this can be trickier. 
But definitely, I suggest it!

Answer (score 0):

This question has no relations to grunt or Mamp or AngularJS.  And in fact it's not a problem at all, just preference. mamp prefers to run itself on the port 8888 where as lamp (windows version of mamp) uses port 80. A port is just an entry point to your computer from somewhere.  In a computer there exists up to 65535 ports.

This also means, you can potentially host 65535 websites on a single computer.

If you want your site to run on 8888 then just open the gruntfile.js file and search for 9000 and change it to 8888 then done.

And if you wanted to, you can also change the port that mamp runs itself through some of the config files but it's a little harder.

One key thing about all this to take home is that your website shouldnt run on a port that already has something. For example if you have Skype opened it usually runs on port 80, so if you want to run a website on port 80 then you'll have to close Skype first.